# How to fix HTML Row in C#

Tags: c#, html

i am trying to generate rows into a table using HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell. I am able to output the first part (opening balance) successfully. However, there is a problem in my code that is outputting all results in a single line that is not inside the table. If you see the transactions section this is where the error begins. Please see the code below and suggest a solution.

```html
            HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell tb = new HtmlTableCell();

            //IF data not returned empty
            if (openingBalanceList[0].Openingbalance != "")
            {
                string cellValue = fromDate;
                tb.Attributes.Add("scope", "row");
                tb.InnerText = cellValue;
                tRow.Controls.Add(tb);

                 tb = new HtmlTableCell();
                 cellValue = "B/F Balance";
                tb.InnerText = cellValue;
                tRow.Controls.Add(tb);

                tb = new HtmlTableCell();
                cellValue = "";
                tb.InnerText = cellValue;
                tRow.Controls.Add(tb);

                tb = new HtmlTableCell();
                cellValue = "";
                tb.InnerText = cellValue;
                tRow.Controls.Add(tb);

                cellValue = openingBalanceList[0].Openingbalance;
                tb.InnerText = cellValue;
                tRow.Controls.Add(tb);

                warningDiv.Visible = false;
                printWarning.InnerText = "";

                infoDiv.Visible = false;
                printInfo.InnerText = "";

                successDiv.Visible = false;
                printSuccess.InnerText = "";
               double openingBalance = Convert.ToDouble(openingBalanceList[0].Openingbalance, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                cls_transactions[] transactionlist = iMalLiability.getLatestTransactions(account,fromDate,toDate, openingBalance);

                int transactionlistlength = transactionlist.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < transactionlistlength; i++)
                {

                    if (transactionlistlength > 0)
                    {


                        cls_transactions transaction = new cls_transactions();
                         tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                        tb.InnerText = transactionlist[i].TrnDate;
                        tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
                         tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                        tb.InnerText = transactionlist[i].TrnDescription;
                        tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
                        double amount = transactionlist[i].TrnAmount;

                        if(amount>0)
                        {
                             tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                            tb.InnerText = "";
                            tRow.Controls.Add(tb); 
                             tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                            tb.InnerText = Convert.ToString(transactionlist[i].TrnAmount);
                            tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                            tb.InnerText = Convert.ToString(transactionlist[i].TrnAmount);
                            tRow.Controls.Add(tb);
                            tb.InnerText = "";
                            tRow.Controls.Add(tb);               
                        }
                        openingBalance = openingBalance + amount;
                         tb = new HtmlTableCell("");
                        tb.InnerText = Convert.ToString(openingBalance);
                        tRow.Controls.Add(tb);               
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new instances of `HtmlTableCell` each time you want to add a new cell, but you only ever create one instance of `HtmlTableRow`.  So they're always being added to the same one row.

On each iteration of the `for` loop, create a new row and add it to the table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < transactionlistlength; i++)
{
    tRow = new HtmlTableRow();

    // add your cells as you currently do

    // add the row to the table here
}
```